# underscore js map array with optional object parameters

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got following code:

```
setStatus = false;
_.map(array, function (element) {
    return {
    name: element.type,
    status: element.status
    })
```

I'd like to optionally set 'status' parameter. F.e when setStatus variable is false then elements in mapped collection would be containing 'name' parameter only;

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a simple condition.

```
        var setStatus = false;
        _.map(array, function (element) {
            if (setStatus) {
                return {
                    name: element.type,
                    status: element.status
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    name: element.type
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var setStatus = false;
_.map(array, function (element) {
    var obj = {name: element.type};
    if(setStatus) obj.status = element.status;
    return obj;
})
```